# iptable does not block port 80, rule does not work

Tags: iptables

I have configured my iptable to block port 80, but still I can access port 80 from outside the machine, why is that ? by the way I have tested the ssh 22, if I am not from network 192.168.111.0/24 then the rule works just fine, but for http 80 does not work at all,

here is my simple rule:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8 state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.111.0/24     0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
4    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 0 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:22 ctstate ESTABLISHED
3    REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

by the above configuration the port 80 or 443 should not be reachable at all, while when I am testing from outside server it is reachable, what is the reason, why iptable does not prevemt it ? does the rules are configured wrong ?

Comment: side comment: having state INVALID with a REJECT target is an heresy. Documentation tells to never REJECT INVALID packets, or random failures will happen to TCP connections (late packets out of window etc...). Use DROP.

Comment: Now what is running on port 80? Is that a normal web server, or is it running from a container? A container would be routed and not subject to these rules. Can you supply your whole ruleset using this command instead? `iptables-save -c`

Comment: The port 80 is running on a container, so how I can allow 192.168.200.0/24 on ens161 to reach port 80, and reject all ?

Comment: @mos can you include the output of your FORWARD chain? Forwarded packets (such as those destined for a container interface) would bypass the INPUT chain. See https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: It looks like Docker adds chains that are evaluated before the FORWARD chain as well, see https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/